# Swagger UI shows no APIs

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a Spring Boot Gradle project. I added Swagger but I see no APIs in the UI:
[image: Swagger-ui screen shot]

These are the lines in the build.gradle:

```
compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.7.0")
compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.7.0")
```

This is the Main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.aaa"})
public class Starter {    
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Starter.class, args);
  }
}
```

This is the config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration {    
        @Bean
        public Docket api() {
            return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                    .select()
                    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.aaa.controller"))
                    .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/*"))
                    .build();
        }    
}
```

There is no `@EnableWebMvc`.
I do have some more config classes per profiles but they are only annotated with `@Configuration`, `@Profile` and `@PropertySource`.
I also have a CORS filter - but even when I removed it, swagger did not work.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I had this problem months ago and it was related to Gson. Are you using gson as Json converter ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. You line 'There is no @EnableWebMvc' saved my day